# Problems cloning a file (git)

Tags: git, github

Have anyone problems trying to clone [this repo](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/blob/master/usability/comment-uncomment.js)?

I've tried `git clone https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/blob/master/usability/comment-uncomment.js` but it says *Error: repository not found*.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to clone a file rather than the actual git repository. If you really want to checkout a single file you could use git archive (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).

```
git clone https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions.git
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are not trying to clone the entire repository. If you just want that file, it's probably easier to copy and paste it. Otherwise:

```
git clone https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions.git
```

Should work just fine (it did for me).